# $Order ACCESSING PROTECTED ARRAY

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I am attempting to access the meta data in an $order through a woocommerce order system.  The system has extra order fields .  It is these fields I am attempting to acess.  Every variation I try, just end up with with a server error OR the data is blank on output.  I have tried $MetaData->id, $MetaData[0]['id'], using a foreach loop for each record...etc etc.  It makes no difference, the data, in string form, does not display.  I suspect it has something to do with it being a protected array, which I have no clue as to how to manage...obviously. It is not working.

Here is the code and the some results of the test.

```
$order        = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$order_data   = $order->get_data();  
$MetaData = $order_data['meta_data'];
DebugLog(json_encode($MetaData));

// OUTPUT of JSON_ENCODE:
// [{"id":2658,"key":"business-name","value":"BUSINESS NAME HERE"},{"id":2659,"key":"full-business-address","value":"1028 STREET Dr"},{"id":2660,"key":"city","value":"CITY NAME"},{"id":2661,"key":"state","value":"California"},{"id":2662,"key":"zip","value":"900XX"},{"id":2663,"key":"_subscription_switch_data","value":[]},{"id":2723,"key":"_stripe_customer_id","value":"XXXX"},{"id":2724,"key":"_stripe_source_id","value":"XXXX"},{"id":2727,"key":"_stripe_charge_captured","value":"yes"},{"id":2728,"key":"_stripe_fee","value":"0.45"},{"id":2729,"key":"_stripe_net","value":"4.55"},{"id":2730,"key":"_stripe_currency","value":"USD"},{"id":2736,"key":"_wc_memberships_access_granted","value":{"215":{"already_granted":"yes","granting_order_status":"processing"}}},{"id":2748,"key":"_wc_memberships_access_granted","value":{"215":{"already_granted":"yes","granting_order_status":"processing"}}}]

 foreach($MetaData as $index => $feature)
  {
   $MetaValue = $MetaData[$index ]['key']; 
   DebugLog($MetaValue);
  }
```

The final foreach causes a server error.   I just don't see it and I have tried all sorts of combinations.

I have also tried:

```
foreach($MetaData as $feature)  
  {
   $MetaValue = $feature['key']; 
   DebugLog($MetaValue);
  }
```

and

```
$MetaValue = $MetaData[0]['key']
```

Same results. Any idea? What am I missing in this most basic of programming tools?

Comment: What server error do you get? Have you checked whether `$MetaData` is an array or an object?

Comment: It is an array. and it is a general error "Internal Server Error"..shown on the woocommerce checkout page.  Code stop working at that point.

Comment: using the code: DebugLog($MetaData) comes up with an array type.  The $MetaData comes from $MetaData = $order_data['meta_data'];

Comment: `$Order->get_meta('key')` - cant you do something like that with Woo,  Or `get_post_meta($Order->ID, 'key');`

Comment: I tried that too...same results

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE!  GOT IT**
Wild ride. You have to create the pointer to the row (MetaData, but then treat each row as it's own array with indexes.

THE SOLUTION

```
  $order        = new WC_Order( $order_id );
  $order_data   = $order->get_data();  
  $MetaData = $order_data['meta_data'];

  foreach($MetaData as $SubRow)
  {
  DebugLog($SubRow->id);
  DebugLog($SubRow->key);   
  DebugLog($SubRow->value);     
  }
```

Thanks to all who wrote and got me to think out of the box a bit.